# How to change default hash password in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, hash, sethash

I have an existing website (functional) and now i need to upgrade my website by cakephp and also, import old DB to new DB.

Cakephp have default Algorithm for hash and password for that i need to change Algorithm .

My old website used this code for password:
`$password_hash = hash('sha256', $password);`

How can I set cakephp password hash auth like: `hash('sha256', $password)` until my website users can login into cakephp script?

please help...

`cakephp ver: CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9<br><br>`

**note**: apologize For the weak English

Comment: CakePHP version 0.2.9? Do you mean version 2.9?

Comment: @ojendays CakePHP version is at the end of version.txt file. You copied "@since         CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9" line. Copy the last one for Cake version.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using CakePHP 3.x which uses the bcrypt hashing algorithm by default.

To use sha256 hasing you can create custom password hasher class.

```
namespace App\Auth;
use Cake\Auth\AbstractPasswordHasher;

class Sha256PasswordHasher extends AbstractPasswordHasher
{
    public function hash($password)
    {
        return sha256($password);
    }

    public function check($password, $hashedPassword)
    {
        return sha256($password) === $hashedPassword;
    }
}
```

and configure the AuthComponent to use your own password hasher:

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'passwordHasher' => [
                    'className' => 'Sha256',
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]);
}
```

read more here https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#hashing-passwords

Answer (score 0):

SHA3-512 is not supported in cakephp version 2.x, and in cakephp version 2.x we can use at max SHA-512.
You can do the same by making changes in app/Controller/AppController.php by adding below patch,

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
            'Form' => array(
              'passwordHasher' => array(
                   'className' => 'Simple',
                   'hashType' => 'sha512'       //passing sha512 as the hash type
              )
            )
         );
```

If you are giving a option to change/reset password after updating your hash, you may use below patch to accept password with updated hash,
**$var = Security::hash($password, 'sha512', true);**
Here sha512 hash algorithm will be used, you can change it as per your hash requirement(sha1/sha256/md5/blowfish), if salt value i.e. third parameter is set to true application's salt value will be used.

Comment: here what is `Security::hash`? Where is this defined? any path? Thanks.